# JPA repository .save in Netty server channelInitializer handler not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty

I have initialized the socket channel in the Netty server but I have faced an issue with the handler, when I want to save the received data from the client to MySQL through JPA it can not be saved.

```
package com.servernetty.server;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ServerApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class ServerService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerService.class);
    private final TestRepo testRepo;

    @Autowired
    public ServerService(@Value("${hs.host}") String host, @Value("${hs.port}") int port, TestRepo testRepo) throws Exception {

        this.testRepo = testRepo;
        EventLoopGroup booGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap().
            group(booGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128) 
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .localAddress("127.0.0.1", port).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline.addLast(new NettyServerHandler());
                        }
                    });

            logger.info("You are here in message server port no: " + port);
            ChannelFuture channel = bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            logger.info("finallllllll: " + port);
            booGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
    
    private final TestRepo testrepo;

    public NettyServerHandler(TestRepo testrepo) {
        this.testrepo = testrepo;
    }
    /**
     * The message sent by the client will trigger
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        TestModel trans = new TestModel();
        trans.setId(11);
        trans.setTestf("d11");
        trans.setTransactionType("test");
        log.info("before save");
        try {
            testrepo.save(trans);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.info("tttttttttttttt" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        log.info("after save");
    }
}
```

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }, name = "TEST_UNIQUE_ID"))
public class TestModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "bigint unsigned")
    private Integer id;

    String testf;

    @Column(name = "transaction_type")
    String transactionType;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTestf() {
        return testf;
    }

    public void setTestf(String testf) {
        this.testf = testf;
    }

    public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }
}
```

```
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import com.servernetty.server.model.TestModel;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<TestModel, Integer> {

}
```

[The folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVRki.png)
The exception that I receive

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.servernetty.server.handlers.NettyServerHandler.channelRead(NettyServerHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

In logger I receive the "before save" but nothing after that, the application stacks.

Appreciate your help

Comment: What do you mean by the application stacks...please show the exception..

Comment: It neither shows any exception nor goes forward.

Comment: do you have @component on top of your NettyServerHandler  class, also print testrepo before your log.info("beforeSave"), I wonder if it is null

Comment: I added @component on top of NettyServerHandler class, but nothing changed. The print of testrepo is null.

Comment: what version of spring-boot do you use? Are you using ComponentScan?

Comment: I am using spring version 2.5.5

Comment: I need to your where your application class is located in the folder picture :) plus its code as well.  The class that has @SpringBootApplication on it

Comment: Updated the question and folder structure.

Comment: Do you have <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>   dependency?

Comment: Yes, it works when calling api from comtroller.

Comment: It could be then how you are calling ServerService.  Are you using @Autowired, or also doing new ServerService()??

Comment: I am using @Service and it loads the service.

Comment: you have a problem all the way from the top of your structure.   At some points you are doing Autowire, and at somepoints you are passing though a constructor.  If you use constructors, then Springboot will not be handling these beans for you...which means you will have such problems.  MY suggestion, remove all constructors, and use only Autowire.  Right now your repo is null..so find out why.  Put logs from the first class being called (Controller) and see at what point it becomes null

Comment: I removed all the constructors and added Autowired instead still the testRepo is null. When calling from controller it works with constructor and Autowired but the issue is with the socketChannel.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code and removed all (new) and all (Constructors).  It is best to let Springboot Autowire everything for you:

Pay attention to how ServerService and NettyServerHandler are implemented.

```
package com.example.socketchannel;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SocketchannelApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocketchannelApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

---

```
package com.example.socketchannel.controller;

import com.example.socketchannel.service.NettyServerHandler;
import com.example.socketchannel.service.ServerService;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class ServerController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyServerHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private ServerService serverService;

}
```

---

```
package com.example.socketchannel.service;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import io.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap;
import io.netty.channel.*;
import io.netty.channel.nio.*;
import io.netty.channel.socket.*;
import io.netty.channel.socket.nio.*;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LogLevel;
import io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler;

@Service
public class ServerService {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServerService.class);

    //You need to add hs.host to your properties
    @Value("${hs.host:127:0.0.1}")
    private String host;

    //You need to add hs.port to your properties.
    @Value("${hs.port:9090}")
    private Integer port;


    @Autowired
    private NettyServerHandler nettyServerHandler;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {

        EventLoopGroup booGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

        try {
            ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap().
                    group(booGroup, workerGroup)
                    .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.DEBUG))
                    .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
                    .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
                    .childOption(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
                    .localAddress("127.0.0.1", port).childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                            ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
                            pipeline.addLast(nettyServerHandler);
                        }
                    });

            logger.info("You are here in message server port no {}", port);
            ChannelFuture channel = bootstrap.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            logger.error("Encounterd Exception", e);
        } finally {
            logger.info("finallllllll: {} ", port);
            booGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.socketchannel.service;

import com.example.socketchannel.model.TestModel;
import com.example.socketchannel.repository.TestRepo;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext;
import io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter;

@Service
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(NettyServerHandler.class);

    @Autowired
    private TestRepo testRepo;

    /**
     * The message sent by the client will trigger
     */
    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        TestModel trans = new TestModel();
        trans.setId(11);
        trans.setTestf("d11");
        trans.setTransactionType("test");
        logger.info("before save");
        try {
            testRepo.save(trans);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("tttttttttttttt" + e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("after save");
    }
}
```

---

```
package com.example.socketchannel.repository;

import com.example.socketchannel.model.TestModel;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface TestRepo extends JpaRepository<TestModel, Integer> {

}
```

---

```
package com.example.socketchannel.model;


import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;

@Entity
@Table(name = "test", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "id" }, name = "TEST_UNIQUE_ID"))
public class TestModel {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "bigint unsigned")
    private Integer id;

    String testf;

    @Column(name = "transaction_type")
    String transactionType;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTestf() {
        return testf;
    }

    public void setTestf(String testf) {
        this.testf = testf;
    }

    public String getTransactionType() {
        return transactionType;
    }

    public void setTransactionType(String transactionType) {
        this.transactionType = transactionType;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>socketchannel</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>socketchannel</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-netty</artifactId>
            <version>1.41.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-all</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0.Alpha2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

---

```
Validating that the springboot context runs, if you do mvn clean install

package com.example.socketchannel;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;

@SpringBootTest
class SocketchannelApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

---

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building socketchannel 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev-local/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev/io/grpc/grpc-core/maven-metadata.xml (0 B at 0.0 KB/sec)
Downloading: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev-local/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://arm.lmera.ericsson.se/artifactory/proj-cv-dev/io/grpc/grpc-api/maven-metadata.xml (2 KB at 10.5 KB/sec)
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) @ socketchannel ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ socketchannel ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 6 source files to C:\UCA-Development\cvc-clones\services\socketchannel\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ socketchannel ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered properties files.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\UCA-Development\cvc-clones\services\socketchannel\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ socketchannel ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\UCA-Development\cvc-clones\services\socketchannel\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ socketchannel ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests
14:01:36.120 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate from class [org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate]
14:01:36.140 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating BootstrapContext using constructor [public org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultBootstrapContext(java.lang.Class,org.springframework.test.context.CacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate)]
14:01:36.228 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.BootstrapUtils - Instantiating TestContextBootstrapper for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests] from class [org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper]
14:01:36.251 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests], using SpringBootContextLoader
14:01:36.260 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/example/socketchannel/SocketchannelApplicationTests-context.xml] does not exist
14:01:36.261 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Did not detect default resource location for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]: class path resource [com/example/socketchannel/SocketchannelApplicationTestsContext.groovy] does not exist
14:01:36.261 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader - Could not detect default resource locations for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
14:01:36.262 [main] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils - Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]: SocketchannelApplicationTests does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
14:01:36.351 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.ActiveProfilesUtils - Could not find an 'annotation declaring class' for annotation type [org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles] and class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]
14:01:36.542 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider - Identified candidate component class: file [C:\UCA-Development\cvc-clones\services\socketchannel\target\classes\com\example\socketchannel\SocketchannelApplication.class]
14:01:36.544 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Found @SpringBootConfiguration com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplication for test class com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests
14:01:36.788 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - @TestExecutionListeners is not present for class [com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplicationTests]: using defaults.
14:01:36.788 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener]
14:01:36.823 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@38f116f6, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@5286c33a, org.springframework.test.context.event.ApplicationEventsTestExecutionListener@6e6d5d29, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@5c530d1e, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@6c25e6c4, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@85e6769, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@c5ee75e, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@48a12036, org.springframework.test.context.event.EventPublishingTestExecutionListener@bf1ec20, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@70efb718, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@b70da4c, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@4a11eb84, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@4e858e0a, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@435fb7b5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.webservices.client.MockWebServiceServerTestExecutionListener@4e70a728]
14:01:36.829 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - Before test class: context [DefaultTestContext@3f07b12c testClass = SocketchannelApplicationTests, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [WebMergedContextConfiguration@4bd1f8dd testClass = SocketchannelApplicationTests, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.example.socketchannel.SocketchannelApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}', contextCustomizers = set[org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@4bbf6d0e, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@2415fc55, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@5e21e98f, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@7b993c65, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@6692b6c6, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@192d43ce], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]], attributes = map['org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.activateListener' -> true]], class annotated with @DirtiesContext [false] with mode [null].
14:01:36.903 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.TestPropertySourceUtils - Adding inlined properties to environment: {spring.jmx.enabled=false, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true}

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.6)

2021-10-31 14:01:38.142  INFO 6128 --- [           main] c.e.s.SocketchannelApplicationTests      : Starting SocketchannelApplicationTests using Java 11.0.7 on SE-00018098 with PID 6128 (started by ezsusmu in C:\UCA-Development\cvc-clones\services\socketchannel)
2021-10-31 14:01:38.150  INFO 6128 --- [           main] c.e.s.SocketchannelApplicationTests      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-10-31 14:01:41.285  INFO 6128 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-10-31 14:01:41.439  INFO 6128 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 135 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-10-31 14:01:46.495  INFO 6128 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-10-31 14:01:47.188  INFO 6128 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-10-31 14:01:47.567  INFO 6128 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-10-31 14:01:47.852  INFO 6128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.32.Final
2021-10-31 14:01:48.528  INFO 6128 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-10-31 14:01:49.292  INFO 6128 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2021-10-31 14:01:51.596  INFO 6128 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-10-31 14:01:51.617  INFO 6128 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-10-31 14:01:53.868  INFO 6128 --- [           main] c.e.socketchannel.service.ServerService  : You are here in message server port no 9090
2021-10-31 14:01:57.647  INFO 6128 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0x23fb4903] REGISTERED
2021-10-31 14:01:57.651  INFO 6128 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0x23fb4903] BIND: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9090
2021-10-31 14:01:57.655  INFO 6128 --- [ntLoopGroup-2-1] io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler  : [id: 0x23fb4903, L:/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9090] ACTIVE
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use spring-boot-starter-jdbc, you will not face the issue.